# JavaScript, как повесть две функции на onclick?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!

Есть кнопка, в которой событие onclick:

```
<input type="submit" value="Заказать звонок"  onclick="yaCounterXXXXXX.reachGoal('4'); return true;">
```

Мне нужно, что было не только:

```
yaCounterXXXXXX.reachGoal('4'); return true;
```

а ещё:

```
dataLayer.push({"event": "zayavka_obratnyiy_zvonok"});
```

Подскажите как это сделать.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вот смотрите - последовательное выполнение четырёх функций

Четвёртая функция очищает блок

```js
function one() {
  res.innerHTML = "Я первая функция";
  res.style.color = "red";
  setTimeout(two, 2000);
  console.clear();
}

function two() {
  res.innerHTML = "Я вторая функция";
  res.style.color = "green";
  setTimeout(another, 2000);
}

function another() {
  res.style.color = "blue";
  res.innerHTML = "Я третья функция";
  setTimeout(resp, 2000);
}

function resp() {
  res.innerHTML = " ";
  console.log("Я четвёртая функция - и я очистила блок")
}


btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  one();
})
```

```html
<button id="btn">Я кнопка</button>
<p id="res"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  // Объявляем функцию обработки события клика (имя функции произвольное)
  function onSubmitBtnClick() {
    yaCounterXXXXXX.reachGoal('4'); 
    dataLayer.push({"event": "zayavka_obratnyiy_zvonok"});
    return true; 
  }

  // При событии "содержимое DOM загружено", еще до полной загрузки страницы, мы уже можем работать с элементами
  // Тут в качестве обработчика добавляется анонимная стрелочная функция: () => {}
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    let submit = document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]');  // выбираем элемент. Селектор чисто для примера - в реальном коде лучше использовать более конкретный (а еще лучше, кнопки выбирать по id)
    submit.addEventListener('click', onSubmitBtnClick);  // добавляем элементу наш обработчик события "click" - указываем имя функции
  }); 
</script>
```

Впоследствии можно добавить еще обработчики, через тот же метод `addEventListener`. Тогда,  переменную указывающую на элемент, лучше объявить глобально.
А назначать обработчики событий инлайн (в атрибутах `on<eventname>`) - не самая хорошая практика: помимо головной боли с навешиванием нескольких обработчиков, это порождает еще и лишние сложности с контекстом и `this`... что в некоторых случаях вынуждает делать лишние обращения к DOM, или даже костылить те вещи, которые иначе (при назначении методом) решились бы проще и эффективнее.

Answer (score 0):

Выполнить две функции подряд

```js
function f1() {
    console.log("выполнение функции 1")
}

function f2() {
    console.log("выполнение функции 2")
}
```

```html
<div onclick="f1(); f2();"  style="width: 100px; height: 25px; background-color: #777777; border-radius: 10px;text-align:center;padding-top:3px;cursor:pointer;" >кнопка</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

В onclick добавляете обе функции:

```html
<input type="submit" value="Заказать звонок"
    onclick="yaCounterXXXXXX.reachGoal('4'); dataLayer.push(
        {"event": "zayavka_obratnyiy_zvonok"}); return true;">
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]